# Comparing performance between individuals across time with variable number of measurements

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have data for multiple people, where each person performs and is graded on a task an arbitrary number of times each year across multiple years.  E.g. -

```
          year 1          year 2         year 3
Person1   1 1 3 2 4       2 3 3          5 2 3 4 1  
Person2   2 3 1           7 9 1 2        3 3 1  
Person3  ...
```

So in year 1, person 1 does the task 5 times and gets scores 1 1 3 2 4.  I take the mean for each person in each year:

```
          year 1          year 2         year 3  
Person1   2.2             2.7            3  
Person2   2               4.75           2.3  
Person3  ...
```

How do I test for a significant difference between people in the means for each year?  I assume that I could do a repeated measures ANOVA on the means, but this ignores the number of measurements per person per year.  For example, for person 1 in year1, there are 5 measurements compared to 3 for person2 in year1, making the former measurement more certain.  In general, some people can have far more measurements than other people across all years.  Thanks.